# DVD drive not reading

Tags: windows-xp, dvd

My friend is running Windows XP on an ASUS N-MX-SE Plus board.  DVD drive, an LG GSA-H54N DVD RW drive, won't read disks.  The drive appears in BIOS and on My Computer, but won't read any disk in it (D:\ is always an empty folder whether there's a disk in the drive or not). I updated the firmware and the problem persists. Is there anything else I can do to fix this?

Comment: Check you power lines to DVD drive. sometimes DVD drive will not be getting enough power from SMPS. use a multimeter to check voltage level.

Answer (score 0):

I've had an issue where my drive won't burn any DVDs, it would throw very diverse errors: `I/O` error, `calibration` error, even `fixation` error (yes, once the disk was burnt and throwing everything to the trash). It ran on a power source with a single power output (like those that resemble a laptop charger). I checked it and it was delivering a constant `12V` and `5V` and it was rated for `80W`, more than my drive would need. But anyway, I got a `250W` internal power source and did the [paperclip trick](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-power-up-an-ATX-Power-Supply-without-a-PC/?lang=es) to turn it on. Connected my drive and tested it. It burnt 6 complete `4.5 GB` to `4.7 GB` ISOs without any issue, so I would blame:

1. The power capacity of the `PSU`. It may be topping its capacity. Try removing any additional drives and PCI cards. Check your temperature, this is very unlikely but your fans may be drawing some extra power.
2. The voltage. Check if the tension delivered is `12V` or `5V` continuous.
3. The drive itself. It may just be [#REKT](http://es.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=rekt).

By the way, my drive is a cheap `LG GH24NS90`, it works wonders.